# Various issues with a sticky footer in a vertical flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position, sticky-footer

**Expected result:** `#footer` sticks to the end of `#container` visible region. `#content`is only hidden behind the footer until `#container` if fully scrolled down.

---

**Chrome**: *as expected*

**Firefox**: `#footer` sticks to the end of `#container` visible region, but bottom of`#content` stay hidden behind it when `#container` is scrolled to the end instead of being placed on top of `#footer`.

**Safari**: `#footer` doesn't stick, it is positioned as it would have with a static position.

---

Tested on macOS with latest version to date of each browser.

All browsers should handle it right [according to mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) and [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky), so is this a bug or I am doing it wrong ?

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  overflow: auto;
}
#content {
  flex: none;
}
#footer {
  flex: none;
  position:sticky;
  bottom:0;
}

/* styling purpose */
#container, #content, #footer {
  border:8px solid;
  opacity: .6;
 }
```

```html
<div id=container style="height: 100px; border-color: green">
  <div id=content style="height: 200px; border-color: red"></div>
  <div id=footer  style="height:  20px; border-color: blue"></div>
</div>
```

This snippets just shows the issue, I'm actually making use of the flexbox properties in my code, otherwise `#container` would of course just be a normal block.

Comment: Do u want the footer at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: @Manikandan2811 Yes, I made it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1):

try using -moz and -webkit hacks sticky is not yet fully supported

Comment: did you try position: -webkit-sticky; or -webkit-position:sticky;

Comment: Both. Does it work for you ? Which browser are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `position: fixed;` no? `sticky` has very bad browser-support, wait until you test mobile^^

```css
#content {
  overflow: auto;
  padding-bottom: 50px; /* height of footer */
}
#footer {
  position: fixed; left: 0; bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

/* just for styling purposes */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
#container {
  height: 100vh;
}
#content {
  background: teal;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 200vh;
}
#footer {
  background: lightcoral;
  height: 50px;
}
[data-before]:before {
  content: attr(data-before);
}

[data-after]:after {
  content: attr(data-after);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    <p>Content on top</p>
    <p>Content near footer</p>
  </div>
  <div id="footer" data-before="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know I could use `position: fixed`, but that would imply having to hard code the height of the footer as the content bottom-margin ( or padding in your code sample ), as well as loosing the flexible alignment properties of the footer. This might be the only solution however.

Comment: Actually I couldn't use `position: fixed` in my code as `#container` is deep in the DOM and there is no way I could hard code the bottom margin. My only solution is to add a wrapped div relatively positioned around `#container` and use  `position: absolute`  for `#footer`.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently this is a known issue and is still not assigned:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1377072

The simple solution is to make the flexible region as a wrapper around the content. The only drawback is that we lose the flexible properties of the footer but that's managable.

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#content {
  flex: none;
}
#footer {
  position:sticky;
  bottom:0;
}

/* styling purpose */
#container, #content, #footer {
  border:8px solid;
  opacity: .6;
 }
```

```html
<div id=container style="height: 100px; border-color: green">
  <div id=wrapper>
    <div id=content style="height: 200px; border-color: red"></div>
  </div>
  <div id=footer style="height:  20px; border-color: blue"></div>
</div>
```